# Database boolean attributes or FK to definition table?

Tags: database, data-modeling

In legacy code I've reviewed, I've found a data model that create boolean fields of relevant attributes where only one is expected to be true.  For example:

```
create table MyTable (
   id int primary key not null,
   // more fields...
   has_x bool not null,
   has_y bool not null
);
```

This is silly because it allows potentially inconsistent data if both are set to true.  I'm trying to explain to technical, but non-developer, users, but not sure how to explain WHY it is proper to change to a 1-to-many relationship to a definition, like below, when the original design "works".

```
create table Attributes ( -- contains "x" and "y" records.
   id int primary key not null,
   name varchar(100) not null
);

create table MyTable (
   id int primary key not null,
   // more fields
   attribute_id int not null foreign key references Attributes(id)
);
```

Is there a term for these data modeling patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

However, you can ensure consistency by implementing a [`CHECK` constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_Constraint) that will only allow one of the boolean fields to be set to true at any one time.

Comment: The foreign key does enforce only one being true due to NOT NULL constraint and the Attributes table containing records for each possibility.  A many-to-many relationship isn't desired in this example.

Comment: np.  You pointed out the term that seems to match this situation.  Thanks!